# Azure Devops pipeline for solution with multiple console application projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pipeline

I have a devops repo that has 6 or 7 .NET Core 6 console applications, and now I am trying to create a pipeline that has a build stage and a release to live stage, but I cannot manage to get it working..

My pipeline currently looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:
     - job:
       steps:
       - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
         displayName: 'Nuget installer'
       - task: NuGetCommand@2
         inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

       - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
         inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
          zipAfterPublish: true
          publishWebProjects: false
        
       - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
         artifact: drop

- stage: 'Live'
  displayName: 'Live'
  dependsOn: 'Build'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
   - deployment: Live
     displayName: Live
     environment: 
       name: 'Live'    
       resourceType: VirtualMachine
     variables:
     - name: websitePhysicalPath
       value: '\\DC01\MyApplication'
     strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps: 
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              inputs:
                SourceFolder: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\3\drop\Release'
                Contents: '**'
                TargetFolder: '\\DC01\MyService'
```

The error I get is:

```
##[error]A publish folder could not be found to zip for project file: .
```

Do you need the full logs to be able to see whats gone wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Answer (score 0):

To repro the issue, I have created dotnet app and the pipeline using your code. I got the same issue. Then I have modified **DotNetCore@2 publish** task as below to resolve the issue.

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true
      publishWebProjects: false
```

[image]